# Nuxt3: Detect when component is unmounted?

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

I need to clear some intervals before component is unmounted. In Vue there is [beforeUnmount(...)](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#beforeunmount). What is the equivalent in Nuxt3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt3 renders the html on the server rather than on the client and vue takes over on the client and hydrates the html sent from the server so you would use `beforeUnmount` as usual. Since `beforeUnmount` unmounts a vue app, it's only called client side anyways since you don't have a vue app on the server.

In pages folder, say you have a file called `index.vue`

```html
<script setup>
onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  console.log('before unmount')
})
<script>

<template></template>

<style scoped></style>
```

You go about these things the same way you usually would in a normal vue app, the only thing is nuxt auto imports things for you, has an opinionated folder structure set up for you to use and a bunch of other things, but it still is a framework for vue and the typical lifecycle hooks that you are used to using still apply.